# Font is changing on Safari iPhone

Tags: html, css, ios, fonts

My problem is that when I view my website on other browsers it shows the font-family Calibri as intended but when viewed on safari in iPhone it changes. I dont know why this is happening. To view my website go to this- https://www.skewminds.com. I use the following styling code for my body-

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #282A35;
}
```

Any ideas on it?

Answer (score 0):

Calibri does not seem to be included on iPhone OS. This will be true of most fonts outside of this list: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

If you want something more custom you can use a service like Google Fonts which lets you include the font file(s) as part of your site.